# complex query is not working on spark scala and hive

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Im trying to execute this query below on spark using scala.

```
var query hiveContext.sql("""

select
    s_acctbal,
    s_name,
    n_name,
    p_partkey,
    p_mfgr,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    s_comment
from
    part,
    supplier,
    partsupp,
    nation,
    region,
    q2_min_ps_supplycost
where
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
    and p_size = 37
    and p_type like '%COPPER'
    and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
    and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
    and r_name = 'EUROPE'
    and ps_supplycost = min_ps_supplycost
    and p_partkey = min_p_partkey
order by
    s_acctbal desc,
    n_name,
    s_name,
    p_partkey
limit 100;

""");
```

In hive:

```
 select
        s_acctbal,
        s_name,
        n_name,
        p_partkey,
        p_mfgr,
        s_address,
        s_phone,
        s_comment
    from
        part,
        supplier,
        partsupp,
        nation,
        region,
        q2_min_ps_supplycost
    where
        p_partkey = ps_partkey
        and s_suppkey = ps_suppkey
        and p_size = 37
        and p_type like '%COPPER'
        and s_nationkey = n_nationkey
        and n_regionkey = r_regionkey
        and r_name = 'EUROPE'
        and ps_supplycost = min_ps_supplycost
        and p_partkey = min_p_partkey
    order by
        s_acctbal desc,
        n_name,
        s_name,
        p_partkey
    limit 100;
```

But its not working in spark and also dont works in hive.

In spark, it completes the first 5 stages, but then when arrive to the next stage the process don't proceed. And stays in this stage doing nothing, because it appears in the "Tasks: Succeeded/Total" tab always 0/2. And the process stays in this stage always until the disk get full. When the disk get full it shows an error.

In hive the process starts ok but then arrives to the job number 4 and this starts to happen:

```
Launching Job 4 out of 15
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2016-04-09 01:07:20,601 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 01:08:20,688 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 01:09:20,747 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 01:10:20,820 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
```

Until the disk gets full, and then this error happens:

```
Launching Job 4 out of 15
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2016-04-09 02:30:41,660 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:31:42,146 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:32:42,262 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:33:42,330 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:34:42,386 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:35:42,456 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:36:42,520 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:37:42,592 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:38:42,799 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:39:42,861 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-04-09 02:40:42,933 Stage-36 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:369)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:601)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.fatal(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Ended Job = job_local939866218_0002 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 14211146527 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-36:  HDFS Read: 1517492910 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
hive>
```

Comment: first what happened with this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/36510966/3415409

Comment: plus it says there is no space left on the device ! so did you check for available space ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im trying to do the query in a different way, with a view.There is available space, but I think the query breaks because of the complexity.

Comment: I would rather address that 'no space left on device' issue first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a lot of disk space. 40GB is not enough to execute this query?

Comment: When this job number 4 starts I have 41GB of free space. And the job returns always map = 0%, reduce =0% until the disk gets full.